# Distributing 20 Apples, 30 Bananas, 40 Oranges among 8 children.(Solution Verification)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I want to distribute 20 Apples, 30 Bananas, 40 Oranges among 8 children. If there are no restrictions the number of ways should be:
$${20+7\choose 7} { 30+7\choose 7}{ 40+7\choose 7}$$
and if each child should get at least 1 apple, 1 banana and 1 orange the number of ways should be:$${12+7\choose 7} { 22+7\choose 7}{ 32+7\choose 7}$$

Comment: Just read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Comment: Both your answers are correct, although you should explain how you arrived at them.

Answer (score 1):

From the reference to *Stars and bars* above, I guess we can try together!

Let's look at just one of the fruits, since the total will just be the product of any number of fruits. I like apples, so let's choose them. Placing 20 apples into 8 nonempty bins (8 kids) will give

$$
{{n-1}\choose{k-1} } = {{20-1}\choose{8-1} }= {{19}\choose{7} }
$$

And then you just multiply for every fruit. So, yeah, you got it right, but your proof should have more reasoning, I guess.